# Generics and Nullable (class vs struct)

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0

**EDIT:** *see my update below on my stance on Null in C#8.0 before giving me options to patterns and such*

---

**Original question**

I am trying to upgrade my base libraries to be "null enabled", aka using the C# 8.0 `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` flag.

When trying to work with abstractions, and in specific generics, I ran into some problems. Consider the following code snippet which takes in an `Action` and converts this to a `Func<TResult>`. This is *pre-nullable-enable*:

```
public static Func<TResult> ToFunc<TResult>(this Action action)
        => () => { action(); return default; }
;
```

but *post-nullable-enable* I seem to struggle, since I cant make TResult nullable (or `TResult?`) as wit would require a constraint of either `where TResult: class` or `where TResult: struct`. There is no way I can combine these two constraints to let the compiler know that TResult can be a class or a valuetype. Which at the moment I find annoying - as one should be able to express *it doesn't matter whether class or struct, it'll be nullable* (regardless of previous .NET intherited design).

So, *post-nullable-enable* I seem to have only one option, and that is code duplication, examples below:

```
public static Func<TResult?> ToFuncClass<TResult>(this Action action)
        where TResult : class
        => () => { action(); return null; }
;

public static Func<TResult?> ToFuncStruct<TResult>(this Action action)
        where TResult : struct
        => () => { action(); return null; }
;
```

Both the *code duplication* as well as the *naming schemes* that come with it bother me a lot. I might be misunderstanding proper usage, or maybe I'm missing another feature of the spec, but how would you solve this?

---

**UPDATE**: In fact, I think I'd rather stick to my own *"null-handling" implementations* than using C#8.0's nullable feature. As a *"Void"* object or fleshed out *"Option/Maybe/None"-solution* seems to communicate things better. The only thing I am concerned about is that **it isn't very helpful** in **moving the language forward**, **training new coders** and introduces another **third party/non native solutation** to a **universal** provlem we all have **dealing with null**. 
Because *own implementations of handling with null* are great and all, but come up *differently* in each code base, need to be maintained by the community, and you have various different flavours. So it would be so helpful and hugely beneficial if the language enforced it fully, and if a *standard* rised. Which I hoped this would be - clearly it is not, and I understand. But I feel this is a missed opportunity.

Thx
Yves

Comment: There's no duplication. The types are *completely* different in each case, which is why this isn't considered method overloading.

Comment: The compiler has to emit **very** different code for nullable structs vs nullable reference types. That's why you cannot express "nullable, no matter what flavour"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever to be perfectly clear I *understand* that behaviour, but it is rather clunky to see this in a codebase, where effectively you used to do it in one method for each case and be done with it. Imagine this for everyone generic method, I feel this is overlooked - even if underlying types (value/reference) are different, the behaviour I want to express is clearly the same in both cases. Now when calling the method upon a type I can't just call ToFunc, but will have to check the type of result I'll get back (makes no sense here even) and either choose ToFuncX or To FuncY.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe it's not overlooked, the reason is explained and there's no way around this. If anything, the strange thing is having a method that intentionally returns *null*. Why use nullable reference types then

Comment: @YvesSchelpe what is the *real* problem you want to solve? Functional languages don't return `null` from methods, they return a `unit` or `void` type. You can do the same.`System.Threading.Channels` contains a `VoidResult` type for this reason.

Comment: The compiler could make this work, given sufficient effort. C# has traditionally been designed in such the way that the costs you get for using a feature are up-front (so no compiler magic with a lot of overhead) but that principle has long since gone the way of the dodo with things like iterator methods, async state machines and the whole machinery for closures and lambdas. The more pertinent reason is "there's no way to implement this without breaking existing code". Had there been no `Nullable<T>` before this feature, it could have been done, but as that is a thing now, no dice.

Comment: You could use the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) or a [Result type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Result_type) instead of returning null. How are you using these methods? What problem do they solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use my own "null"-eqsue type indeed, for the mere fact of expressing there is "nothing". I would've thought this feature would be a good resolving factor. Yet community solutions are still better. As jeroen mostert explains it could've been possible and still can be, if they design away from the concept of Nullable<T> which restricts the language moving forward imho. Because using your own types "Void" etc.. introduces only more confusion in stead of a natural adoption where everyone understands what is what when reading the code. That is the *main issue* for me.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe and yet you use `null` for something it's not meant for.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do use those patterns, I just think it's sad that introducing this half-baked feature now lead to certain expectations. Maybe they should not have done this in C#8.0... Or do a drastic change, to move the language forward. Now it's a compromise - which is not a good thing in terms of readibility, and new people coming in. As they have to be aware of the various different implementations Null Object patterns. I'd rather don't have it, than this half-baked feature as I feel it now does only add confusion.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *"and yet you use null for something it's not meant for"*, please explain yourself? How can you infer that from my examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is explained in [Try out Nullable Reference Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) in the section `The issue with T?`. Essentially, there's no way around this.

First, what is `T` when we use `T?`? Is it nullable or non-nullable ?

> A natural definition of T? would mean, "any nullable type". However, this would imply that T would mean "any non-nullable type", and that is not true! It is possible to substitute a T with a nullable value type today (such as bool?).

Second, the types used in each case are different - a `string?` is still a `string` while an `int?` is a `Nullable<int>`. The generated *concrete methods* in each case are completely different. In one case you get a

```
Func<string> ToFuncClass<string>(this Action action)
```

In the other, you get a

```
Func<Nullable<int>> ToFuncStruct<int>(this Action)
```

> Next, it’s important to note that a nullable reference type is not the same thing as a nullable value type. Nullable value types map to a concrete class type in .NET. So int? is actually Nullable. But for string?, it’s actually the same string but with a compiler-generated attribute annotating it. This is done for backwards compatibility. In other words, string? is kind of a "fake type", whereas int? is not.

The article's example demonstrates this :

> This distinction between nullable value types and nullable reference types comes up in a pattern such as this:

```
void M<T>(T? t) where T: notnull
```

> This would mean that the parameter is the nullable version of T, and T is constrained to be notnull.
>
> If T were a string, then the actual signature of M would be :

```
M<string>([NullableAttribute] T t)
```

> but if T were an int, then M would be

```
M<int>(Nullable<int> t)
```

> These two signatures are fundamentally different, and this difference is not reconcilable.

Comment: Thx for the clear explanation, but doesn't this prove that they should'nt have introduced nullable. _This is done for backwards compatibility_ implies that we are stuck with a feature that could've been very valuable to express your code & readability of your code into now essentially code duplication - just for the fact of backwards compat. I would rather have systems redesigned for it then. I'll stick to my old null-patterns I'm afraid, as I simply can't use this at the moment. I understand the semantic difference and need for it if backwards compat is needed - but I fear then it's useless.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe no, backwards compatibility isn't affected and the benefit is huge without code duplication. I added NRTs in old projects and didn't have to duplicate anything. The `ToFunc` methods though are *definitely weird* - they return dummy values and reintroduce the very problem NRTs are meant to fix. What are you trying to solve with this? If you want to convert actions to functions, why not use one of the *common* patterns, like returning [a Null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), or create your own `Void` object?

Comment: as I said, I would to that, I wanted to simplify the example.
_common patterns_ might be so for your, but 90% of people I code with don't know of them, so having it in the language properly supported would bet better than this feature now where you still have to rely on your own (or inherited) implementations of dealing with null (eg Null Object pattern or Void object and many other solutions in fact). 
But I understand there's no way around it now, as they've implemented it. I just don't see the value in it, certainly not for moving the language forward.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe I'm having the exact same problem using C#7. My signatures are `public static T GetOrCreate<T>(ref T value, object syncRoot, Func<T> factory) where T : class` and `public static T GetOrCreate<T>(ref T? value, object syncRoot, Func<T> factory) where T : struct`. Both methods contain arround 7 lines of code totally identically between each other. This is C#7 and I hoped that C#8 will give me a possibility to solve that.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann indeed - I had different hopes for the feature. For me it doesn't solve anything I couldn't do before with the implementation I have using the "Option" pattern. Yet this introduces another level of abstraction or reliability you need to maintain - and explain to newcomers in your codebase, whilst I feel the language could handle this. Maybe in time...

Comment: @YvesSchelpe: It does solve big problem: NullReferenceException, because many programmers fail to check for nulls, simply do not expect it to arrive in parameters. That is the main reason for nullable references. Second, you do not need two names, just one. Code duplication, sure, but that is not so big price to pay (considering the two types are somehow unrelated). I would wish that `Nullable<T>` would become language/CIL construct that would accept both classes and structures, but it is really too early for something like that.

Comment: @firda unfortunately, two names are needed because the two function signatures are identical except for the return type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How could Sebastian have two `GetOrCreate` overloads? Was just about to test it when I saw his comment... and simply believed it works.

Comment: @firda My overloads contain `T` as parameter. Parameters are included in method signatures. Yves `T` is only contained in return type. The return type does not belong to the method signature. That's why he needs two different method names.

Comment: @firda I agree programmers need to be aware of null. I just wished they'd done this properly - it'll only add more confusion (do not forget your can suppress a lot of the errors/warnings and a lot of it introduces clause like `#nullable enable` inside codebases). This is not a step forward. I'd rather have them adopt a programming style like the `Option` pattern, so API designers are forced to express intent and consumers are forced to deal with "something" or "nothing". I guarantee this will not solve the issue and only complicate things further. So I'll stick to my own "Option"...

Comment: @YvesSchelpe: If only C# had something like template-specialization in C++. That could have solved this as well (`Nullable<T> where T: class` being a simple reference without the embedded bool used for structs), but this is C# and they hade to make it backwards compatible... I do agree that it looks like half-measure, imperfect, but still good. It is improvement in my point of view, a good try. Will see how is it going to be adopted.

Comment: @firda and YvesScelpe this *really* isn't a chat site.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, but the case is the feature is potentially more harmful than it is in solving it's problems. And I think people need to be aware of it. If 75% of the official documentation is about the exit strategies (null-forgiving operator, the countless directives, etc..) - I think it should be made aware. So sorry for discussing it. Point in case, your answer is right, alas I don't like the philosophy, but technically it is what it is now. Sadly.

Comment: The linked article makes the (to me) non-obvious assertion that: *A natural definition of T? would mean, "any nullable type". However, this would imply that T would mean "any non-nullable type", and that is not true!* - because most naturally, I'd reject that notion; T? should have been nullable, regardless of whether T is or not. The fact that the two methods aren't reconcilable is irrelevant, because neither are M<SomeClass>() and M<SomeOtherClass>() - and when it comes to structs, at runtime, each instantiated generic type is separately JITted anyhow.